# Unable to access child files using physical path

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have an issue with access child files using Sitecore Powershell script

- I have created powershell script under
     `/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/Tasks` to copy
     files from a physical folder `E:\FolderA\` to another folder under
     my site `E:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\upload\FolderA\`
- The powershell script didn't return child files and return 0 files
     found.
- Note that if I save the script in any directory out from Sitecore and
  run it using powershell it works and copy all the data.

This is my script:

```
$sourcepath = "E:\FolderA\" 
$targetpath = "E:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\upload\FolderA\"
"$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd-HHmmss) Getting files from source $sourcepath" | 
 out-file -filepath $logFile -append

#$allsourcefiles = get-childitem -path $sourcepath
#"$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd-HHmmss) Found " + $allsourcefiles.Count | out-file 
 -filepath $logFile -append

$initialDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$endDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(1)
$allsourcefiles = get-childitem -path $sourcepath
"$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd-HHmmss) Total found " + $allsourcefiles.Count | out-
file -filepath $logFile -append
```

Comment: Does the IIS App Pool identity that's running Sitecore have read access to the source directory? You may want to check access permissions on that source folder.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works after I add read access to app pool identity.

Comment: In the future please paste the gist as text rather than an image.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your comment, I removed the image and replaced it with the code :)

Answer (score 1):

solved by add read access permissions to IIS App Pool identity that's running Sitecore and add read access permissions  to have read access permissions on the source directory.